# How do I code against an unhandled exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling, try-catch

I have this code. I enter three grades into 3 different textbox and then click a submit button that displays the grades in a listbox. Works well except for this. When I enter one or two grades only and click submit I get error message "Exception was unhandeled". How would I code this to prevent this from happening. The Error Happens here.

```
 ' retrieve the student's grades
    grades(studentCount, 0) = Convert.ToInt32(test1TextBox.Text)
    grades(studentCount, 1) = Convert.ToInt32(test2TextBox.Text)
    grades(studentCount, 2) = Convert.ToInt32(test3TextBox.Text)


       Private Sub submitButton_Click(sender As Object,
   e As EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click

    ' process one student's grades

    ' retrieve the student's grades
    grades(studentCount, 0) = Convert.ToInt32(test1TextBox.Text)
    grades(studentCount, 1) = Convert.ToInt32(test2TextBox.Text)
    grades(studentCount, 2) = Convert.ToInt32(test3TextBox.Text)

    ' begin creating String containing the student's grades and average
    Dim output As String = "Student " & studentCount & vbTab

    ' append each test grade to the output
    For column = 0 To grades.GetUpperBound(1)
        ' if the Letter RadioButton is checked
        If letterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            ' append letter grade to the output
            output &= vbTab & LetterGrade(grades(studentCount, column))
        Else
            ' append number grade to the output
            output &= vbTab & grades(studentCount, column)
        End If
    Next

    ' append the student's test average to the output
    output &= vbTab & CalculateStudentAverage(studentCount)

    gradesListBox.Items.Add(output) ' add output to the ListBox
    studentCount += 1 ' update number of students entered
    lblClassAverageResult.Text = CalculateClassAverage() ' display class average
    DisplayBarChart() ' display the current grade distribution

    ' clear the input TextBoxes and set focus to first TextBox
    test1TextBox.Clear()
    test2TextBox.Clear()
    test3TextBox.Clear()
    test1TextBox.Focus()

    ' limit number of students
    If studentCount = grades.GetUpperBound(0) + 1 Then
        inputGradesGroupBox.Enabled = False ' disable GroupBox's controls
    End If
End Sub ' submitButton_Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the error is happening with your Convert.ToInt32 Statements, try using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).  You can use a Try/Catch/Finally Statement to catch any errors that you have, but the better way in my mind would be to code around the errors in your program that are common and use the Try/Catch routine for exceptional errors.

From above Link:

> The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

If you want to display an error if one of the fields is not filled out you could do something like this.

```
Dim grade1, grade2, grade3 As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(test1TextBox.Text, grade1) Then
    grades(studentCount, 0) = grade1
Else
    'Message Box here
End If

If Int32.TryParse(test2TextBox.Text, grade2) Then
    grades(studentCount, 1) = grade2
Else
        'Message Box here
End If

If Int32.TryParse(test3TextBox.Text, grade3) Then
    grades(studentCount, 2) = grade3
Else
    'Message Box here
End If
```

or if you just want to Parse it and do not care about a zero amount you could do something like this:

```
Dim grade1, grade2, grade3 As Integer
Int32.TryParse(test1TextBox.Text, grade1)
Int32.TryParse(test2TextBox.Text, grade2)
Int32.TryParse(test3TextBox.Text, grade3)

grades(studentCount, 0) = grade1
grades(studentCount, 1) = grade2
grades(studentCount, 2) = grade3
```

---

Edited per Comments

```
If Integer.TryParse(test1TextBox.Text, grade1) Then
    grades(studentCount, 0) = grade1
Else
    HandleInputError(0) 'This is a Subroutine with common code  in it for showing MessageBox and Clearing text
    Exit Sub
End If
```

HandleInputError Subroutine

```
Sub HandleInputError(grade As Integer)
    MsgBox("Please Re-Enter Grade #" & (grade + 1).ToString, vbExclamation, vbOKOnly)
    Select Case grade
        Case 0
            test1TextBox.Text = ""
        Case 1
            test2TextBox.Text = ""
        Case 2
            test3TextBox.Text = ""
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: top scenario still parses zeros to listbox after clicking ok on message box, can you just clear everything out some how

Comment: @JasonSmith I Realize that, I just added it to show you could put some conditional logic to handle the error, what specifically are you wanting to do when there is no text entered in a textbox

Comment: I don't want anything to parse over. Would like to clear the textbox and make use enter the grade number then enter next textbox grade until all three textboxs have grades in them.

Comment: @JasonSmith just show your MessageBox when they click ok then clear the TextBoxes and use `Exit Sub` to exit your Click EventHandler

Comment: @JasonSmith just edited the answer to show what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

It's called Error Handling. Here is an example:

```
Try
    Process.Start("http://www.microsoft.com")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Can't load Web page" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
End Try
```

Basically you put whatever you suspect it might give you an exception between the "`Try`" and "`Catch`" statements. There is also a `Finally` statement. Read on to learn more about error handling.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6da8809(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx